# flutter change icon by condition inside ListTile

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

hello I have List with some of data and I would like to set leading by condition
after use my func i get this error
type '_CompactLinkedHashSet<Set>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget?'

what I wont is set color for status.
Where I make a bug ?
there is my list tyle

```
ListTile(
                  title: Text(model.content[index].name),
                  subtitle: Text("${model.content[index].status}"),
                  leading: status(model.content[index].status),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
            )
```

and there is my function

```
  status(status) => {
  if(status == "done"){
     Icon(Icons.check_circle,
         color: Colors.green)
  }else if (status == "working"){
    Icon(Icons.check_circle,
        color: Colors.blue)
  }
  else{
   Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.red)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you `return` the Icons in your `status` function? Because right now, your status function doesn't do anything. No returning and no assigning.

So, like this:

```
if (status == 'done') {
  return Icon(Icons.check_circle);
}
```

Also, there is a syntax error in your status function declaration:

```
status(status) => {
...
}
```

Should be (no arrow function when you use curly braces, unlike what you'd do in React, added missing parentheses, added return type).

```
Icon status((status) {
...
});
```